# Basic widget: listed but cannot be added to homescreen

Tags: android, android-widget

I am for the first time checking how to make a widget app. The first thing I want to do is add a widget to the home screen, a basic textview with a static text. Nothing else.

After reading the [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) I tried to construct one. I get to the point that the widget is listed by the system, I run normally the configuration activity. But when I drag and drop the widget to the homescreen, nothing happens. I don't know where to debug, when I do debug my Widgetprovider class all looks fine (resources are not null, view gets updated) so I don't know where to look for an error message.

What is wrong?

At least some direction on where to look would be very appreciated!

Here's the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tizanacode.ExJakdojade">

<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="WidgetConfigurationActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Watched Line"
        android:name="ExJakdoJade" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/ex_jakdojade_info" />
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Here is the provider class:

```
public class ExJakdoJade extends AppWidgetProvider {

private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            ExJakdoJade.class);
    /*int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {*/
    for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        // Create some random data
        int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.layout);
        Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));
        // Set the text
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, String.valueOf(number));

        // Register an onClickListener
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExJakdoJade.class);

        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

}